# Not able to upload files above 1MB using apollo-server-micro & NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo, graphql-js

Hope you could help me out with the following. I am trying to upload an excel file of ≈3MB from the client side to the API by first converting the file to a DataURL where after I send it as a string. This is working for smaller files, but it somehow seems to be blocking my larger files.

When I upload the file, I get the following error.

```
POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?
```

I have done my own research and found more people with the same problem, though I could not find a solution.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/792

This is the code I am using on the server side.

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-micro'

type Props = {
    _id: string
    file: string[]
}

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Mutation {
        uploadFile(file: [String!]!): Boolean!
    }
    type Query {
        readUpload(_id: String!): Boolean!
    }
`

const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        async uploadFile(_: any, { file }: Props) {   
            console.log(file)
            
            return true
        }
    },
    Query: {
        async readUpload(_: any, { _id }: Props) {
        }
    }
}

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs, 
    resolvers
})

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
}

// Ensure to put a slash as the first character to prevent errors.
export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/uploads' })
```

This is the code I am using on the client side.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'

import { uploadFile } from '../graphql/fetchers/uploads'
import { UPLOAD_FILE_QUERY } from '../graphql/queries/uploads'

export default function Upload() {
    const inputElement = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

    const submitForm = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const files = inputElement.current?.files

        if (files) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader()

            fileReader.onload = async () => {
                try {
                    const result = fileReader.result as string
                    try {
                        console.log(result)
                        await uploadFile(UPLOAD_FILE_QUERY, { file: result })  
                    } catch(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }           
                } catch(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]) 
        }
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <input ref={inputElement} type='file'></input>
            <button onClick={(event) => submitForm(event)}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
}
```

set bodyParser to true

Answer (score 0):

Set `bodyParser` size limit

```
export const config = {
   api: {
     bodyParser: {
        sizeLimit: '4mb' // Set desired value here
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you try to send file as string in json? I think you should use multipart/form data on client side and parse them with special middleware on server side
On client special link converts request to multipart/formdata
full example https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples

```
import { useMemo } from "react"
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context"
import { getUserTokenFromLocalStorage } from "../utils/utils"
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client"
let apolloClient

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: "/api/graphql",
  headers: {
    "keep-alive": "true",
  },
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  let token = getUserTokenFromLocalStorage()
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  }
})

function createIsomorphLink() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    const { SchemaLink } = require("@apollo/client/link/schema")
    const { schema } = require("./schema")
    return new SchemaLink({ schema })
  } else {
    return authLink.concat(httpLink)
  }
}

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: createIsomorphLink(),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState)
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _apolloClient
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}
```